# DocPad: Empty or Missing YAML Elements

Tags: docpad

I have the following in one of my Layout files...

```
<% for link in @document.nextlink[0..0]: %>
    <% if (link.name): %>
        <ul class="actions">
            <li><a href="<%- "#{link.name}" %>" class="button button-icon fa fa-file"><%- "#{link.helptext}" %></a></li>
        </ul>   
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This works great.  Unless, nextlink is not in my YAML at all.  But that's what I want.  Sometimes I want to have that button called Next and sometimes I do not.

if nextlink is not in my YAML, the DocPad compiler throws an error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The obvious example is to check for the existence of nextlink before running your loop (<%if @document.nextlink:%>). If this isn't what you mean, can you give an example of your YAML?

Comment: Thank you!  I had tried that before, but left off the colon (:).  Much gratitude!!